# Are there any unpublished downsides in Windows 8 Regular?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I intend to buy new notebook and I have two options either buy one with Windows 8 Regular or one with FreeDOS which is ~100USD cheaper, while retaining the specs. Because I'm in academia I have an option to get Window 8 Pro for free through academic program.

I have checked the comparison chart at [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8-1/compare/default.aspx) webpage and it seems that I would not miss the features not included. On the other hand my colleague reported that e.g. for Windows Phone development you need W8 Pro or higher.

I'm a developer myself, although I do not intend to do any work for mobile devices, I was concerned if there are any other potential troubles with the regular edition of W8.

I most interested in limitations concerning development in Visual Studio et. al. and running virtual machines under W8.

PS: The academic license is only valid while I'm in academia, so when I leave I will be left without Windows license, thus having one on hand would be nice. On the other if there are any major downsides with regular edition I would use the money saved on laptop purchase to get a proper W8 Pro in future.